# Question regarding the Y̅=C(Y̅–T̅)+I(r)+G̅ function

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, economic-growth

How could we include I(r), a non-constant variable, while Y̅, on the other side of the equation, is constant?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that $Y$ is a constant? Look at the right side of your equation.
$Y$ is determined by the variables included in the right side, so each time one of these variables changes, $Y$ changes.

From a mathematical point of view, you cannot say if a quantity represented by a symbol is a constant or not just looking at an equation, it should be said aside, that is it must be said outside the equation, for example "$\alpha$ is a constant in $\mathbb{R}$", "$G$ is a constant", and so on.

And in an economic model it is the same:  in a model must be established *a* *priori*, in advance, which quantities are *exogenous* variables (that is, taken as fixed, determined *outside* the model) and which are *endogenous* variables, determined *by* the model (that is, the unknowns of the system of equations that constitute the model).

These are basic and very important notions when you study macroeconomic models.

**[edit]**: you have modified your question, so my answer now is less appropriate.

As for your new question, if $Y$ is a constant, you can, of course, in principle, have a non constant variable on the right side. This implies, simply, that when the non constant variable, as $I(r)$, varies, there is an other variable on the right side that varies at the same time, as to mantain $Y$ constant, at the same level.

This is true in general from a mathematical point of view, I don't understand very well what's your particular problem in your example.

If *all* variables are fixed except $Y$ it is not possible have $Y$ fixed and $I$ changing arbitrarily.

Maybe, you want to solve for $r$ so that you find the value of $r$ that makes the equality true, as when one wants to construct the IS curve.
But this just my guess.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer! You wrote: " when the non constant variable, as I(r), varies, there is an other variable on the right side that varies at the same time, as to mantain Y constant, at the same level." Could this be the variable C(.)? How could it be, when it depends on Y and T, which are constant? Thanks!

Comment: What you say is true in general, if there are other variables, besides $I$ that can vary. Think of an equation as $10 = 6+2+ x$. The equality is true if $x=2$. You cannot change $x$ and give it a value different from $2$. But if you write $10=6+y+x$ you can change $x$ as you want, provided that you change also $y$ as to mantain the equality. I wrote also "If all variables are fixed except  it is not possible have  fixed and  changing arbitrarily." So, if Y, T, etc, are all fixed, you can't change $I$, you can't give to $I$ a value different from the value that fulfils the equality.

Comment: A different question is if you are looking for a value of $r$, for which the investment $I(r)$ (investment depends on $r$) fulfils the equation, for a given value of $Y$. This Is what we do when we look for the equation of the $IS$ curve.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer! So in that case, can we assume that I (Investment) is fixed, so I(r) is also fixed, although I(r) it doesn't have the 'constant' symbol?

Comment: Yes, If the equality must hold, for a given value of $Y$ ,the investment must be fixed at the level that ensures equality. If $Y$ changes,  also this value of $I$ has to change. The 'constant symbol on $Y$ means that $Y$ has a given value, from which we can calculate the equilibrium $I(r)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome!